# ¿Cómo subir, actualizar, editar una pagina web sin usar cpanel?

Tags: webservice, dominio, hosting

Soy nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo web, acabo de adquirir mi hosting y dominio, por defecto me ponen cpanel y configurar el ftp para hacer las modificaciones pertinentes.

Mi pregunta va más enfocada a ver si hay otras opciones además de esas dos, lo que quiero es improvisar mi flujo de trabajo.

Comment: No es una pregunta fácil de responder, ya que depende en gran medida de la forma en que vas a gestionar tu sitio. Es decir, si el contenido lo vas a manejar mediante un CMS: Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal ... o si lo manejarás tú directamente mediante FTP. Actualmente se suele usar un CMS, pudiendo al mismo tiempo personalizar tu contenido mediante la modificación de plantillas, hooks, plugin y otros. En cuanto a esto: _lo que quiero es improvisar mi flujo de trabajo_, no entiendo lo que quieres decir.

Answer (score 1):

La mas rápida para desarrollo web en un servidor compartido que no tienes acceso SSH para mi ha sido [Git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp), que ademas te permite trabajar con un versionador como git de tu código. Con un solo comando subes solos los archivos que hayas tenido cambio.

Si tienes ssh, pues con git a traves de la consola de comandos ssh.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a modificar directamente archivos, recuerda que el espacio de almacenamiento de tu servidor no es más que un espacio dentro de un disco en otro ordenador, puedes conectarte a él por FTP, o SFTP, o por medio de cualquier protocolo que tu serivicio de hosting tenga habilitado en la máquina que mantiene tu web. Depende del hosting. Imagino que el que usas será compartido y te proporcionaran unas herramientas concretas para gestionarlo. Te recomiendo que descargues FileZille o Cyberduck y configures tu cuenta FTP, o que pruebes a usarlo con alguna herramienta que integre git.

También podrías instalar tu propio panel de administración que te permita subir archivos o modificar el contenido; o bien usar un CMS.

Si te refieres también a editar o manejar tus bases de datos, pues lo más recomendable y que seguro te proporciona tu hosting es phpmyadmin. Por supuesto existen otras muchas herramientas que tratan de facilitarte esta interacción con la base de datos y que puedes configurar con tu hosting, basta con una simple búsqueda en Google.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!